# System.Environment and System.Threading.Thread - Using directive is unneccesary

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-statement

I am getting " Using directive is unneccesary" error on these two. What is the correct way to use them ?

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear to me: _"A `using namespace` directive can only be applied to namespaces; `Environment` is a type not a namespace"_. What do you expect that line to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove them, as Thread and Environment are not namespaces, but types, as also stated in the warning you get

```
using System.Threading
using System; // which already exists as the first using statement
```

Using statement is for including namespaces, which contain types, like classes, enums, and so on. By adding `System.Threading` for example, you gain access to `Thread` class.

Read Microsoft's explanation for more information;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use usings like you have, sort of, you can name them such as

`using Thread = System.Threading.Thread;`

or

`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

For info
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx